# Exporting Test case to email seeing error The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name

Tags: tfs

I have a Test Suite in TFS that has been run and I am attempting to export it and send to email via the export option in the TFS Test Case web view.

I select my test suite, choose export then click the email button.  The test suite populates on the next screen and I enter my name.  I hit send and then I get an email that says:  Your email request could not be completed due to a server error. Contact your administrator to understand the reasons of failure or retry your request again. JobId: 52059484-7a04-4767-91c4-c82339ba03b1

When I look at the job via the TFS job monitoring I see this:
Result: Failed
Priority:   10
Queued Reasons: Queued
Host:   [TEAM FOUNDATION]DefaultCollection
Job Name:   ExportToHtmlSendMailJob
Agent:  [SVPW-TFS1] w3wp.exe
Queue Time: Tuesday, August 13, 2019 8:11 AM
Queue Duration: 0:00:00.576
Start Time: Tuesday, August 13, 2019 8:11 AM
Run Duration:   0:00:01.487
End Time:   Tuesday, August 13, 2019 8:11 AM
Result Message: System.Xml.XmlException: The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.
 at System.Xml.XmlDocument.CheckName(String name)
 at System.Xml.XmlAttribute..ctor(XmlName name, XmlDocument doc)
 at System.Xml.XmlDocument.CreateAttribute(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceURI)
 at System.Xml.XmlDocument.CreateAttribute(String name)
 at System.Xml.XmlElement.SetAttribute(String name, String value)
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TestManagement.HtmlParser.ParseAttributes(XmlElement xmlElement)
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TestManagement.HtmlParser.ParseHtmlContent()
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TestManagement.TestCaseXmlGenerationHelper.WrapInDiv(String text)
 at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TestManagement.TestCaseXmlGenerationHelper.AddTestStepData(XmlElement rootNode, TestStepModel testStep, Int32 index, Int32 sharedStepIndex)
 at

Other test suites are able to be exported fine.  I would expect this on to be too.

Comment: What's the detail name of this specific test suite? Do it contain some special charter, such as colon `:` ?

Comment: No it doesn't name is 40 91886 Securing PII Isolutions SFP.  I've been digging through everything looking for a :

Comment: Hi ShaneP I also tried some tests on Azure DevOps 2019 in my side, could not reproduce this issue. What's your detail TFS version? A way may narrow down the issue, try to **clear your local TFS cache** and import again, which may do the trick.

Comment: TFS vs 2017.3 - no luck on clearing the cache either still an issue.

Comment: According to your description, all other test suites works  properly.  Did it also works for a new created test suite? If so, suggest you try to use another workaround, new or clone a test suite with the same. Then try to do the  export option again. To clone the test suite you could use Test Case Explorer extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.TestCaseExplorer